# Illegal instruction 4 on all macs but mine

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

I'm including [Eonil's FileSystemEvents](https://github.com/Eonil/FileSystemEvents) as a sub project

I followed the owner's [instructions](http://eonil-observatory.tumblr.com/post/117205738262/a-proper-way-to-add-a-subproject-to-another-xcode): Drag in, then `Link Binary With Libraries` in `Build Phases`

It works just fine when I build it and run it from Xcode. But when I Archive it, it crashes on launch, saying it couldn't find the framework I added.

I then went to `Build Phases` and added a `Copy Files Resource`, and added the `EonilFileSystemEvents.framework` file there, with destination set to `Frameworks`

The archived version now runs on my own Mac, but crashes on three other Macs I've tried on (MBA 2012, OSX 10.10.5, MBA 2013, OSX 10.10.4 and MBP 2014 10.10.5).

When I run the app from the terminal, I get the `Illegal instruction 4` error. Knowing that it might not work I tried adding `-mmacosx-version-min=10.10.0` under `other linker flags` in `Build Settings`

I'm using Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001)

I'm also using Sprite Kit in the app, but the rest is standard stuff.

More

- [Github repository](https://github.com/mortenjust/droptogif)
- [Example crash report](https://gist.github.com/mortenjust/5d80709a6dd4ddf354f4)

Comment: What is the nature of the crash on the Macs where it crashes?  Maybe show us some of the crash log.

Comment: It actually just renders the app, then closes it again immediately, no errors. When I run it from terminal I get the `illegal instruction 4` error. Is there a way to get a more elaborate crash log?

Comment: Do any messages appear in the Console system log when it closes immediately?

Comment: Added all code here https://github.com/mortenjust/droptogif

Comment: And a crash report here https://gist.github.com/mortenjust/5d80709a6dd4ddf354f4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to read a preference from UserDefaults that had not yet been set, and was also trying to read another variable that was nil only when in release mode.